# super.init en Swift

Tags: swift

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer herencias de clases, y hay algo que no entiendo.
Primeramente, os enseño el código.

```
class Persona {
var edad : Int
var nombre : String
var telefono : Int
init(edad: Int, nombre: String, telefono: Int) {
    self.edad = 0
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.telefono = 123456789
  }
}

class Cliente: Persona {
var credito : Int
init(credito: Int) {
    self.credito = 0
    super.init(edad: <Int>, nombre: <String>, telefono: <Int>)
  }
}
```

Pues bien, al escribir en la subclase el `super.init`, Xcode me avisa de que tengo que darle los parámetros, cosa que quisiera dárselos al crear un objeto de la subclase. Si lo intento crear:

`var unCliente = Cliente(credito: Int)`

sólo me deja darle el parámetro crédito y no los parámetros de la clase madre Persona.

Entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿debo darle los parámetros al crear la subclase?
¿Es posible hacer lo que intento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `init` de la clase `Persona`, a menos que quieras tener un valor por defecto creado con esos datos o lo puedes cambiar a:

```
init(edad: Int, nombre: String, telefono: Int) {
    self.edad = edad
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.telefono = telefono
}
```

Cuando creas un objeto de tipo `Cliente` y quieres inicializar la super clase, debes agregar los parámetros en el `init` de la clase hija:

```
init(credito: Int, edad: Int, nombre: String, telefono: Int) {
    self.credito = credito// Le cambié por = 0
    super.init(edad: edad, nombre: nombre, telefono: telefono)
}
```

Ahora veamos como funciona:

1. Creamos un objeto de tipo array de `Personas`:

   ```
   var persona: [Persona] = []
   ```
2. Creamos dos objetos de tipo `Cliente`:

   ```
   let cliente = Cliente(credito: 10, edad: 36, nombre: “Juan”, telefono: 955)
   let cliente2 = Cliente(credito: 20, edad: 26, nombre: “Pedro, telefono: 789)
   ```
3. Como cliente hereda de persona, podemos agregar los clientes en el array de persona porque ya inicializaste la super clase en el `init` de la clase hija:

   ```
   persona.append(cliente)
   persona.append(cliente2)
   ```
4. Si imprimes los nombres tanto de los objetos de `Persona` y `Cliente` puedes comprobar que son los mismos:

   ```
   print(persona[0].nombre) //Juan
   print(persona[1].nombre) //Pedro
   print(cliente.nombre) //Juan
   print(cliente2.nombre) //Pedro
   ```

Si no quieres tener el `init` en Persona, puedes agregar los valores de la super clase al momento que la inicializas en la clase hija.

```
class Persona {
    var edad : Int = 0 //Defines valores porque la clase no tiene inicializador
    var nombre : String = ""
    var telefono : Int = 0
    init() { }
}
```

Puedes llamar a esos atributos desde la clase hija después de inicializar la super clase con:

```
super.nombre_del_atributo
```

Quedando así la clase hija:

```
class Cliente: Persona {
    var credito : Int
    init(credito: Int, edad: Int, nombre: String, telefono: Int) {
        self.credito = credito
        super.init()
        super.edad = edad
        super.nombre = nombre
        super.telefono = telefono
    }
}
```

El resultado es el mismo que en el numeral 4. de arriba.